# If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, is $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ bounded above by a function only depending on $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f_n\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions that converges uniformly to $f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it then true that $|f_n(x)−f(x)|$ for all $x\in X$ is bounded above by some function only depending on $n$?

The reason for the question is that if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then given any $\epsilon>0$, one should be able to find an $N(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n>N(\epsilon)$ implies $|f_n(x)−f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in X$ . By analogy with showing some function is continuous, I would try to find $N(\epsilon)$ by bounding $|f_n(x)−f(x)|$ from above. To satisfy the definition, it seems like this bound can only depend on $n$, so one can in turn bound it from above by $\epsilon$ and solve for $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the function may be equal to $$\varepsilon (n) =\sup_{x\in X} |f_n (x) - f(x) |$$

Comment: Why may this function not exist for a sequence of functions being pointwise convergent?

Comment: It will always exist as long as you allow $\infty $ to be in the codomain. For uniform converge you need $\epsilon (n) $ to converge to 0 as $n \to \infty $ . Consider the sequence given by $f_n(x)= nx $ for $x \in (0,1/n] $ , $f_n(x)=1 $ for $x \in [1/n, 1] $. This sequence converges pointwise to $f \equiv 1 $ but you see that $\epsilon (n)=1 $.